# $3\sigma^2 \le \mu(1-\mu)$ for unimodal probability distributions on $[0,1]$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $f(x)$ be a normalized continuous probability distribution with support on $[0,1]$. It isn't hard to prove that the following inequality holds in general:

$$\sigma^2 \le \mu(1-\mu)$$

where $\sigma^2$ and $\mu$ are the variance and mean of the pdf $f(x)$.

Now make the further assumption that $f(x)$ is unimodal, in the sense that it has at most one local maximum in $[0,1]$. Does the following stronger inequality hold in this case:

$$3\sigma^2 \le \mu(1-\mu)?$$

If the inequality holds, prove it. If it doesn't hold, give a counterexample (or prove somehow that the inequality doesn't hold), and can you suggest a similar inequality that *does* hold?

Comment: Since $X \in [0,1]$ _almost surely,_ why do we need to be told that we are permitted to _assume_ that $E[X] = \mu$ and $\operatorname{var}(X) = \sigma^2$ have finite value? Could you give us an example of a random variable that takes on values in $[0,1]$ almost surely but does not have finite mean or variance?

Answer (score 1):

This is false.

Inspired by @BruceET's exploratory answer, we take the [Beta distribution $\text{Beta}(\alpha,\beta)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution). The mean $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ are, respectively,
$$\mu = \frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta},\quad \sigma^2=\frac{\alpha\beta}{(\alpha+\beta)^2(\alpha+\beta+1)}.$$
Substitute these expressions into conjectured inequality, we see for this distribution to satisfy the latter, we need 
$$\alpha+\beta\ge 2.$$ 
Any Beta distribution with $\beta\ge1,\,0<\alpha<2-\beta\le1$ would violate the conjectured inequality. Taking derivative of the Beta distribution of random variable $x$, it is proportional to
$$(2-\alpha-\beta)x^{\alpha-2}(1-x)^{\beta-2}\Big(x-\frac{1-\alpha}{(1-\alpha)-(\beta-1)}\Big)<0, \;\forall x\in(0,1).$$
So the distribution is decreasingon $(0,1]$. If we admit infinite value, then this is a counterexample. If we do not, choose a $\delta>0$ and replace the distribution function for $x\in[0,\delta]$ with a linear function such that the resulting function in $[0,1]$ is continuous. Since $\int_0^\delta x^{-(1-\alpha)}\,dx=\frac{\delta^\alpha}{\alpha}$, both the interval $[0,\delta]$ and the probability confined within can be made arbitrarily small --- As a matter of fact the specific form of the probability distribution function is a red herring, since the integral of any Lebesgue integral function can be made arbitrarily small over the domain set of sufficiently small measure. Therefore the modified continuous distribution function approaches the original Beta function in $L^1$ and so do the mean and variance of the former to those of the latter respeectively. Therefore for small enough $\delta$, those distributions violate $3\sigma^2 \le \mu(1-\mu)$.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I hope helpful, but not a proof. Couldn't quite fit into a Comment.

Consider $X \sim BETA(2, 2)$ with $\mu = 1/2$ and $\sigma^2 = 1/20$. 
Then $$3/20 = 3\sigma^2 \le \mu(1 - \mu) = 1/4 = 5/20.$$ 
So it can happen, unless I'm missing something.

But almost flat, yet still barely unimodal, $BETA(1.01, 1.01)$ comes close to equality.
I get  $0.2483444 < 1/4$. (And flat $UNIF(0,1)$ gives equality, but I guess
maybe that's your benchmark.)

Maybe begin by seeking a proof for distributions symmetrical about 1/2 (largest
possible $\mu(1-\mu).$)

Comment: It is indeed helpful, though the opposite of finding a proof. Please check out my answer for counterexamples.